# How to encode wav files to flac format on android

Tags: android, audio, encoding, wav, flac

I have a bytearray that holds an wav audio stream.

Is there a way on android system to convert the wav file to a flac file?

I found some example code from FlacEncoder library but this library assumes as far as I see the use of some audio classes from javax.

These are not available on android.

Is there some other library or some example code for android?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be of some use to you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android