# Convert recorded sound file to flac format (xamarin ios)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I record the sound of on iPhone using `AvAudioRecorder` (xamarin). How convert audio file to .FLAC format using C# (for google speech api) ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in way to do this.  You'll have to use some third party library or write the code to do it yourself.

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a C# wav-to-flac converter right now.

You could simply use [FLACiOS](https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS) with [wav-to-flac](https://github.com/jhurt/wav_to_flac) files embedded into a project in xcode.

Then use native binding of

```
public partial class NativeMethods 
{
    [DllImport("__Internal", 
        EntryPoint="convertWavToFlac", 
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int FlacEncode(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string wav_file, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string flac_file) ;

}
```

and just use bound native method to convert your wav to flac.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of open source C# managed encoders, please check [FlacBox](https://flacbox.codeplex.com/) or [C# Flake](http://cuetoolsnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cuetoolsnet/CUETools.Codecs.FLAKE). See also [Discussion on the latter](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,74242.0.html)