# (Xamarin) Convert audio files from Wav to Flac for (Google) Cloud Speech API

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin, speech-recognition

I am writing a cross-platform application for Android, iOS and Windows (Universal) with Xamarin.Forms. Within the application i am trying to implement speech-to-text (in the Dutch language).

At this point i have that my application can record audio files on all platforms however the audio files are not recorded in the correct format for the [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/) that i am working with. For the API you need to send audio files in the format .Flac, however the audio recorders on the mobile platforms don't support audio recording in the format .Flac.

I am trying to convert the audio recording that is now recorded as a .Wav file the audio file to the .Flac format, however i have not had any success as of jet.

i am trying to use the [JavaFlacEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android?rq=1), however i am not sure if it would work on within Xamarin on all platforms because it is a Java class.

Could someone help me or give me advise with converting a audio file from .Wav to .Flac?

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065260/convert-recorded-sound-file-to-flac-format-xamarin-ios

Comment: Or is there a way in C# to convert a audio file (wav) to flac (without using Xamarin)?

Answer (score 0):

There are number of open source C# managed encoders, please check [FlacBox](https://flacbox.codeplex.com/) or [C# Flake](http://cuetoolsnet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cuetoolsnet/CUETools.Codecs.FLAKE). See also [Discussion on the latter](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,74242.0.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to send `flac` files to the Google Speech engine. It reads `LPCM` files as well. `LPCM` files [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) `WAV` files. All you need to know is the bitrate at which your `WAV` file is sampling. The the basic options can be set as follows:

```
encoding: 'LINEAR16',
sampleRate: 16000 //<- whatever your sample rate is
```