# What is the best lossless real-time audio compression algorithm?

Tags: android, real-time, lossless-compression

I want to transfer a sound over internet instantly, But it has to be compressed before.
the sound will be analyzed at the second side, so I need a lossless compression method. In addition, the lossless compression method need to be FAST enough to work on Android  based system phones.

Comment: You can try to convert your WAV to FLAC (See here for inspirations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android) and then zip it and send it over. Whether or not it's fast enough is left as an exercise to you.

Comment: dear @kha ,  thank u for this is interesting, but i need something like Huffman encoding to encode some samples of sound has been captured by an ordinary android device,  the whole process need to be done as the android device is still capturing.if i did piece of code like u mention using native C++ , could any ordinary phone to do converting while it is  recording without delay?