# Media codec - convert wav to flac

Tags: android, audio, android-mediacodec, flac

I use Audio Record to record audio and Media Codec to convert raw .WAV data buffer to Flac buffer. This Flac buffers are then written to a file which is not playable. As I looked at [Flac file format](https://xiph.org/flac/developers.html), it requires file header and frame header/footer in order to be playable.

This is also the issue with other formats such as audio/mp4a-latm, audio/3gpp, audio/amr-wb (which are Android already support encoders)

For audio/mp4a-latm, I successfully add file header, frame header/footer by follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862715/how-to-generate-the-aac-adts-elementary-stream-with-android-mediacodec). For Flac and other format, is there any wrapper/library to do this (rather than read long/complicated file format document)?

Comment: Recently I used javaFlacEncoder and followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733064/how-to-convert-the-wav-ogg-file-to-flac-file-in-android. I am able to successfully create flac in android. The file size is down to half from wav.

Comment: This code is used to convert .wav file to .flac file. I'm looking for *frame* based converter.